# Django Query Using ORM: Delete all Users with No Posts

Tags: django, orm

I'm after Corey Django Tutorial.

Given the User model & this Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content     = models.TextField(max_length=10000)## was unrestircated
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)#auto_now_add=True - cant updated
author      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I trying to delete using the ORM all the users without any Post, but failing.

Tried to query all the Users and all the users with posts, and then to difference to get the Users_to_delete, but it raises 'NotSupportedError': Calling QuerySet.delete() after difference() is not supported.

**How can I delete all the users without any posts ? (Using the Django ORM)**
Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
User.objects.filter(post__isnull=True).delete()
```

or slightly shorter:

```
User.objects.filter(post=None).delete()
```

It will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `Post` model, and it will only retain the ones where there is a row with the `id` of the `Post` being `NULL`. These are thus the `User`s with no `Post`.

Beware that the admin user will probably *also* be included. You might want to use:

```
User.objects.filter(post=None, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False).delete()
```

This will prevent deleting the `User`s that are super users or staff users.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks!!